# An explicit algorithm to test whether a string of symbols is or is not well-formed in this language.

Tags: logic, computer-science, formal-languages, parsing

Consider the set of five symbols, $\{ (, ), p, ', *\}$. A variable is defined as $p$ followed by zero or more $'$s. A wff is inductively defined as follows: $1$. Every variable is a wff. $2$. If $x$ and $y$ are formulas, so is $(x*y)$. $3$. Nothing else is a formula. This is really just a simplified version of a propositional logic language. My problem, though, is with clause 3 of the definition. It is easy to prove that a particular sequence of symbols is a wff. How, though, does one actually prove that a particular sequence, like $p**pp$, is NOT a wff? More precisely, and this is my real question, is there an explicit algorithm that takes a string and returns Yes if it is a wff, and No if it is not? And can someone describe the algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking a particular question:

> How… does one actually prove that a particular sequence, like `p∗∗pp`, is NOT a wff

and a general question:

> is there an explicit algorithm that takes a string and [ decides if it is a wff ]

The particular question has a shorter answer.  The rules you gave require that a wff must begin with `p` (rule 1) or with `(` (rule 2).  The string `p**pp` begins with `p` so if it is a wff it must be a variable.  But a variable is a `p` followed by zero or more `'`s, and `p**pp` is not that, so it is not a variable.  So by rule 3, it is not a wff.

The more general question has a very interesting answer.

There are many explicit algorithms that do what you want.  They come under the general heading of “[parsing algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages)”.  A parsing algorithm takes an unstructured sequence of symbols and decides if it can be understood as a meaningful utterance in a certain language. In your example the language is the syntax of wffs. Parsing is an interesting topic, and it is impossible to give a complete answer here.  (I highly recommend [Parsing Techniques: A Practical Guide](https://dickgrune.com/Books/PTAPG_1st_Edition/PTAPG.gif) by Grune and Jacobs, available for free download from the author's web site.)

I can outline one example an algorithm that parses the language you described.  This uses the method of *recursive descent* parsing:

- You imagine that the parser will scan over the symbols of the input from left to right.
- You write a function that recognizes a variable.  This is easy: if the next unscanned symbol is `p` the function will consume the `p` and then consume any following `'` symbols, and yield success; otherwise it yields failure, which indicates that the unscanned part of the input does *not* look like a variable
- You write a function that recognizes if the input begins with a wff, and if so scans the entire wff:

  1. It first uses the variable-recognizing function to see if it can recognize a variable at the beginning of the unscanned input.  If so, it yields success, because a variable is a wff.
  2. Otherwise, the function looks to see if the next unscanned symbol is a `(`.  If not, it can fail immediately because every wff that is not a variable begins with a `(`
  3. If the upcoming symbol is a `(`, then it consumes the `(`.  Then it calls itself recursively scan the following wff.  If this recursive call fails, the failure is propagated back up, because what we have is `(` followed by a non-wff.
  4. But if the `(` is followed by a valid wff, the function then looks to see if the following symbol is `*`.  If not, it fails immediately.
  5. But if there is a `*`, the function consumes it and makes a second recursive call, looking for a second wff.
  6. If this second recursive call also succeeds then the function checks to see if the upcoming symbol is `)`, and reports success if it is.

Comment: Well, in regards to the particular question, I just used a particular example, but I could have used any example, one more complicated example. The question is how to prove that a sequence of symbols is not a wff.

Comment: Yes, and I thought perhaps you could see from the example how it might go.